# pass javascript variables into grails params

Tags: javascript, grails

So I need to pass javascript variables into grails parameters to build and download a file.  So initially did this with ajax just to learn that ajax doesn't do downloads.  Initially this worked like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function myFunction() {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "Search/download",
            type: "POST",
            data: {facets: visualSearch.searchQuery.facets()}
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="download">
```

While this passed the mapping correctly, this didn't do downloads.

So now I am want to do something similar with a `g:link`

```
<g:link controller="Search" action="test" params="[facets: '\$(visualSearch.searchQuery.facets())']" >TEST GRAILS</g:link>
```

But all I get in the params in the controller are

```
facets=$(visualSearch.searchQuery.facets())
action=test
controller=search
```

How can I fix this to pass the facets (whether parsed or unparsed) into the controller.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding your javascript variable in `params` will not work. The `g:link` is executed on the server side and has no knowledge of your javascript values. You can remove this `params` and instead add code on the `onclick' event of your link to set your javascript values in the params.

Something like:
In the gsp page,

```
<g:link name="searchLink" controller="Search" action="test">TEST GRAILS</g:link>
```

and then in javascript (in the same page),

```
$(function() {
  $('a[name="searchLink"]').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?facets=' + visualSearch.searchQuery.facets());
  })
})
```

Basically you are using Grails to generate the hyperlink and then using JQuery to append a query string with the parameters to that href

Hope that helps.

Comment: what would the code be?  just `<g:link controller="Search" action="test" onclick="return exportList()" >TEST GRAILS</g:link>` ?

Comment: sorry, still doesn't work, all the `params` has in it is `action=test
controller=search`

Comment: there was a typo. should have been `facet=` See if that works for you. Also tested this snippet here - http://jsfiddle.net/hztYf/

Comment: perfect!  It worked, I had to use visualSearch.searchQuery.value instead of visualSearch.searchQuery.facets since otherwise I was getting back objects, but I should be able to parse it

Comment: Forcing the javascript to be on GSP when it doesn't need to be has a bad smell to it.  Yes, it works.  But it's kind of an anti-pattern in most cases.

Comment: the GSP is only incidental. Why do you think it is an anti-pattern? What would be a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do in these cases is use the `g:link` to generate the URL, but then override the default behavior with jQuery to make the ajax call:

```
<g:link class="searchLink" controller="Search" action="test" params="[facets: '\$(visualSearch.searchQuery.facets())']" >TEST GRAILS</g:link>

$('.searchLink').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default link behavior

  var $element = $(this);
  var url = $element.prop('href');

  $.post(url, function(data) { 
    // callback if you need it
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry a little confused, is the javascript meant to do the controller call or is it meant to get the facets?

Comment: the javascript makes the ajax call to the server using the href that is created via the g:link tag.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have I think you should create a form and submit it in the click event:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function myFunction() {
        $('<form>', {
            "html": '<input type="text" name="facets" value="' + visualSearch.searchQuery.facets() + '" />',
            "action": '${createLink(controller: "Search", action: "test")}',
            "method": 'POST'
        }).appendTo(document.body).submit();
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="download">
```

Or refactor your code to have a real html form and prepare the data for it before submit.